# Passing radio button through forms

Tags: forms, radio-button

I am designing a portfolio where there are five forms. one is a main page, three are different categories of art(each category has a series of four pictures inside, each with a radio button asking which image is the users favorite), and the last is a menu that pops up and tells the user what their favorite piece of art is from each category. Everything works great except the radio buttons. How do I code them so that when one is clicked, it will tell frmTest that lblModel = "blah blah"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please see below example of two radio groups. I've also created simple demo for you [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/KbPuG/):

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="art_a"> Art A<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="art_b" checked> Art B<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="art_c> Art C </br>

<!-- next group -->

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="image_a"> Favorite Image A<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="image_b" checked> Favorite Image B<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="image_c> Favorite Image C </br>
```